# vim iabbrev S to self

Tags: vim

in python is frequently I use `self.` string.
I think in a vim iabbrev similar to this

```
ia S self.
```

but for use this is necesary

```
S<space><bs>var
```

for get

```
self.var
```

how I can implement this idea ?
and only work when the `S` is the first char of word

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not `:iabbrev S self`, then "S." will expand to "self." and the cursor will be just after the ".".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** I found problems with my first response (e.g. when typing `print(s.someprop)` it wouldn't expand, since abbr. of `s.` is a so-called *non-id* abbreviation).

Even simpler would be:

```
iabbrev S self
```

In that case, you would only have to apply a trick to type a *lone* `S`: <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>C-v</kbd>...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in `:help abbreviations`: hit `<C-]>` instead of `<Space>` to do the expansion without inserting a `<Space>`.

Did you consider using a snippet-completion plugin like [Snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) or [SnippetsEmu](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1318)?

Comment: I use snipmate, but for more long snippets, functions, etc. And for snipmate I need use <tab>, I search some more simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the replacement for the abbreviation by hitting the `space`, but as you're aware it will insert a space after the replacement text.

You can also trigger the replacement by hitting `Ctrl-]` which will not insert a space.

There's also a function described in the help that you can define and include in your abbreviation that will eat the added space when using `space` to trigger the replacement.

Type `:help abbreviation`

Then `/eatchar`